# On the fly image size change in JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

So I am creating an image display script that is meant to act like an overlay. I basically want to feed the image size into the animate method so that I can maintain proper image proportions. I am taking the href, using preventDefault, and feeding the URL into the img src that I have in the HTML. Should I just be creating a new img dynamically each time and then using the dynamically created image to read the size of the image and then animating inside a load method? Not sure how to proceed. code follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>


    </head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;

        }

        .overlayIt {
            color: red;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .overlayIt:HOVER {
            color: black;
        }

        #frameIt {
            display: none;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 101;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
            color: black;
            overflow: hidden;
            opacity: 1;
            border: 1px solid white;
            background-color: #000;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: -65px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        #pageOverLay {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: -1;
            height: 1000px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
            opacity: 0;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
    <A href="bullets.jpg" class="overlayIt">CLICK</a><br/>
    <A href="blah.jpg" class="overlayIt">CLICK</a>


    <P/><P/><P/>
    THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT<br>
        THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT<br>

    THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT<br>

    THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT THIS IS SOME TEXT<br>


    <div id="pageOverLay"> </div>

        <img id="frameIt">



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var link;
        var overlayToggle = false;

        function openOverlay() { 
                    $('#frameIt').attr('src',link);
                    $('#pageOverLay').css('z-index','100').animate({opacity: 0.8}, 500, function() {
                        $('#frameIt').css('display','block').animate({height: 500}, 300, function() {
                            $('#frameIt').animate({width: 500}, 500);
                        });
                    });
                    overlayToggle = true;
                };


        function closeOverlay() {
                    $('#pageOverLay').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500, function() {
                    $('#frameIt').animate({width: 0}, 300, function() {
                        $('#pageOverLay').css('z-index','-1');$('#frameIt').css('display','none').css('height','0');
                        });
                    });
                    overlayToggle = false;
        };
        $(function() {
            $('.overlayIt').on('click',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                link = $(this).attr('href');
                openOverlay();
            });
            $('#frameIt').on('click',function() {
                closeOverlay();
            });

            $(document).keyup(function(e) {
                if(e.keyCode == 27 && overlayToggle)
                    closeOverlay();

            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem like this:

I dynamically added the image and then had to check for its dimensions like so -

```
var imag = $('<img style="max-width: 90%;">');

                    $(imag).attr('src',link);
                    $(imag).load(function() {
                        wdth = this.width;
                        hght = this.height;
                    });
```

The main problem with me trying this before is that $(this) and $(imag) would not return the proper dimensions in the load function. I had to use the non-jquery this keyword. Odd behavior.